# Determine if dates between 2 date columns are in the calendar in Power BIi

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, powerbi-custom-visuals, daxstudio

How do I determine using DAX whether the dates between 2 columns (column A and B) are within dates shown in the created calender with an If statement of yes or no for a calculated column?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try following DAX?

---

```
Check = 
IF (
    AND (
        [Date Column A] > MIN ( Sheet2[Date] ),
        [Date Column B] < MAX ( Sheet2[Date] )
    ),
    "Yes",
    "No"
)
```

---

[Sample data Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3xd5.png)
[Sample Calendar Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEgkH.png)

[Output Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxonD.png)

I hope I was able to answer your questions. Cheers.